# NetworkX: Saving Shortest path of OpenStreetMap data as an OGR friendly format

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I am using [this script](https://gist.github.com/rajanski/ccf65d4f5106c2cdc70e) to import OSM data into a GIS based model.

This has to run independent from any software package such as QGIS, PostGIS, or ArcGIS.

I then create a shortest path between two nodes as follow:

```
shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=u'879835512', target=u'879912131')
result_graph = G.subgraph(shortest_path)
```

I would like to visualize (kml?) the results of the shortest path and store them (shp?).

I have a feeling that I need to use the `write_shp` but I think that only works if you have already used `read_shp` which I haven't since I'm importing directly from OSM.

**EDIT 1**:

Based on @gene 's comment, I added the following code:

```
for e in result_graph.edges():
    p0x = result_graph.node[e[0]]['lat']
    p0y = result_graph.node[e[0]]['lon']
    p1x = result_graph.node[e[1]]['lat']
    p1y = result_graph.node[e[1]]['lon']
    edges.append(LineString([(p0x, p0y), (p1x, p1y)]))

nodes = []
for n in result_graph.nodes():
    px = result_graph.node[e[0]]['lat']
    py = result_graph.node[e[0]]['lon']
    nodes.append((px,py))

G2 = nx.DiGraph()

G2.add_nodes_from(nodes)
```

I don't think I'm on the right track yet. as it seems I need to maintain the coordinates somehow with my nodes/links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this:

```
highway_cat = 'motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|road|residential|service|motorway_link|trunk_link|primary_link|secondary_link|teriary_link'
G=read_osm(download_osm(-122.33,47.60,-122.31,47.61,highway_cat))
shortest_path = networkx.shortest_path(G, source=u'1810752839', target=u'3393331431')
parts=[]
for i in shortest_path:
    node=G.node[i]
    parts.append([float(node['lon']),float(node['lat'])])
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYLINE)
w.line(parts=[parts])
w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
w.record(FIRST_FLD='First', SECOND_FLD='Line')
w.save('C:/rubbish/line')
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: Answer works! Curious, do I need to import pyshp to do so? is pyshp part of Geopandas or fiona?

Comment: I found stand-alone module called shapefile.py somewhere on Internet, Trying to find it again and it's not working. But any of above will do. I can upload the one I've used

Comment: Shapefile is part of the pyshp library so it worked for me as well but perhaps if the solution could be geared towards Fiona that'll be perfect :D

Comment: I need efficiency with GIS this is why 99% of the time I am using ArcGIS, I decide to give it a go because I love nx. I guess there are endless options to export results, i.e. modify the code below line w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYLINE). However I think important part of my solution sits above this line 

Answer (score 1):

Simply look at [NetworkX: write_shp](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.write_shp.html)

> Writes a networkx.DiGraph to two shapefiles, edges and nodes. Nodes and edges are expected to have a Well Known Binary (Wkb) or Well Known Text (Wkt) key in order to generate geometries. Also acceptable are nodes with a numeric tuple key (x,y).

You don't need to use `read_shp` before but you must convert the nodes and edges of the digraph to [WKT](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format.

For that, you can use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

Comment: Thanks for providing the info about shapely. I edited my question based on your answer if you'd like :D